# How do I post a review as 'Amazon Customer'?

Tags: amazon

I've just reviewed an e-book which is a blatant ripoff.  50 reviews, all within 2-3 weeks of publication.  All 5 stars, often with exact same contents*.

(seems to be an ongoing thing with Amazon, I dearly wished they copied Yelp and removed astroturf reviews).

The only 2 critical reviews are mine and someone else.  Who had a name before, but now shows up as 'Amazon Customer'.

I don't mind if the author flags my review with Amazon for abuse (there isn't any) but I would rather not have the author go to town thrashing my other reviews.  It has happened before to others when the authors game Amazon.  It also happened to me, a long time ago - plain bad book, not an Amazon shill operation.

So, I'd love to change **this** review to 'Amazon Customer' too.  How do I do it?  I want to leave my other reviews alone, not anonymize my username everywhere.

- you can easily use 'search within reviews' to quickly spot the shills.  Just pick a relevant keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to https://www.komando.com/tips/325536/take-control-of-your-amazon-public-profile-privacy/all which pointed me in the right direction.

(update:  you can get to the settings page faster with this link:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/profile
)

Pick **Accounts & Lists** on the right of the main page.

You get a drop-down menu with all sorts of stuff, like **Your Wishlist, Your Orders**.  Pick a link again called **Your Account**.

Now you get a page with a number of boxes.  **Your Orders, Login and Security, Digital content and devices...**.  You've probably been here before.

You want the box on the left, about mid down the page, called **Ordering and shopping preferences**.  And in that box, pick `Profile`.

Now you end up with a page showing your private profile.

On top, there i a link **This is your private view of your profile. See what others see**.

[image]
`See what others see` does just that.  And you can pick the **Edit Your Profile** button to control your public visibility.

You can change your visible user name, change your review visibility, etc...